# Python stops working after populating QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a student database system where I have defined a function called showStudent which populates the QTableWidget from the list it was passed with in the constructor. I am using SQLite for the database and data is passed correctly but as soon as table.show() is reached program is crashing. Please help, I have failed to get the problem even after too much debugging.

```
def showStudent(list):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    roll=0
    gender = ""
    branch = ""
    year = ""
    name = ""
    address = ""
    mobile = -1
    academic_year = -1

    roll=list[0]
    name=list[1]

    if list[2]==0:
        gender="Male"
    else:
        gender="Female"

    if list[3]==0:
        branch="Mechanical Engineering"
    elif list[3]==1:
        branch="Civil Engineering"
    elif list[3]==2:
        branch="Electrical Engineering"
    elif list[3]==3:
        branch="Electronics and Communication Engineering"
    elif list[3]==4:
        branch="Computer Science and Engineering"
    elif list[3]==5:
        branch="Information Technology"

    if list[4]==0:
        year="1st"
    elif list[4]==1:
        year="2nd"
    elif list[4]==2:
        year="3rd"
    elif list[4]==3:
        year="4th"

    academic_year=list[5]
    address=list[6]
    mobile=list[7]

    table=QTableWidget()
    table.setWindowTitle("Student Details")
    table.resize(500, 300)
    table.setRowCount(8)
    table.setColumnCount(2)

    table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Roll"))
    table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(roll)))
    table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Name"))
    table.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(name)))
    table.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Gender"))
    table.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(gender)))
    table.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Branch"))
    table.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(branch)))
    table.setItem(4, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Year"))
    table.setItem(4, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(year)))
    table.setItem(5, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Academic Year"))
    table.setItem(5, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(academic_year)))
    table.setItem(6, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Address"))
    table.setItem(6, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(address)))
    table.setItem(7, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Mobile"))
    table.setItem(7, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(mobile)))


    table.show()
    return app.exec()
```

This is my DBHelper class which holds the function searchStudent which calls my above function.

```
class DBHelper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn=sqlite3.connect("sdms.db")
        self.c=self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(roll INTEGER,name TEXT,gender INTEGER,branch INTEGER,year INTEGER,academic_year INTEGER,address TEXT,mobile INTEGER)")
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genders(id INTEGER,name TEXT)")
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS branches(id INTEGER,name TEXT)")
    def addStudent(self,roll,name,gender,branch,year,academic_year,address,mobile):
        try:
            self.c.execute("INSERT INTO students (roll,name,gender,branch,year,academic_year,address,mobile) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(roll,name,gender,branch,year,academic_year,address,mobile))
            self.conn.commit()
            self.c.close()
            self.conn.close()
            QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(),'Successful','Student is added successfully to the database.')
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(), 'Error', 'Could not add student to the database.')

    def searchStudent(self,roll):
        self.c.execute("SELECT * from students WHERE roll="+str(roll))
        self.data=self.c.fetchone()
        self.list=[]
        for i in range(0,8):
            self.list.append(self.data[i])
        self.c.close()
        self.conn.close()
        showStudent(self.list)
```

below is where my DBHelper class is instantiated.

```
def showStudent(self):
    showstudent=DBHelper()
    showstudent.searchStudent(14101106001)
```

Comment: You could show the code where you call that function.

Comment: I just tried it and there are no problems, I think hes generated by something else. Just in case `app.exec_()` is an infinite loop and will block any other task that is not inside the widget.

Comment: edited my question. please see that and look if that works for you now or not.

Comment: You could share the .db through drive, dropbox or similar to be able to test it completely.

Comment: `showStudent(self)` or `showStudent(list)` ?

Comment: here is the .db file https://www.mediafire.com/?4fue8ct3uc6ujaa

Comment: showStudent(list)

Comment: I do not understand, in a part of your question you show the following:  `def showStudent(self):
    showstudent=DBHelper()
    showstudent.searchStudent(14101106001)`

Comment: here is the whole .py file.. https://www.mediafire.com/?civr5zi0fnd3qqs

Comment: I recommend not to use the same name for many things, confuses any programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pyqt there should only be one `QApplication` object and it should only be called once to the `QApplication.exec_()`

So I recommend creating a `QDialog` and placing the `QTableWidget` inside the as I show below:

```
def showStudent(list):
        ...
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        table=QTableWidget()
        dialog.layout().addWidget(table)
        ...
        dialog.exec_()
```